# Flutter_riverpod giving me problems while installing

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I am trying to install flutter_riverpod but it gives me these error messages by following the normal approaches on installing packages. That is from pub.dev

I added `flutter_riverpod: ^1.0.4` under my dependencies but gives me an error that says

```
Because riverpod depends on flutter_riverpod ^1.0.4 which depends on riverpod 1.0.3, riverpod 1.0.3 is required.
So, because riverpod is 1.0.0+1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because riverpod is 1.0.0+1, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

Below is my pubspec.yaml file

```
name: riverpod
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.1 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_riverpod: ^1.0.4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

This is the results of running flutter doctor too

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.2, on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 5.15.0-47-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Can you share your pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: Remove the restriction on the flutter_riverpod package and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specific problem is because your project is named `riverpod`. It conflicts with the `riverpod` dependencies of `hooks_riverpod` and `flutter_riverpod`. Rename your project and it will work.

Source: [Version solving failing on running "flutter pub get" for Riverpod with the new Flutter 2.2.2 verison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67796881/version-solving-failing-on-running-flutter-pub-get-for-riverpod-with-the-new-f/67796963#67796963)

Comment: `Because riverpod depends on flutter_riverpod ^2.0.0-dev.9 which depends on riverpod 2.0.0-dev.9, riverpod 2.0.0-dev.9 is required.`. This is the error after your suggestion

Comment: This is after using dev.7
`because riverpod depends on flutter_riverpod ^2.0.0-dev.7 and riverpod is 1.0.0+1, version solving failed`

Comment: I am also using `flutter_riverpod: ^2.0.0-dev.7` but I never get this error.

Comment: Can it be as a result of using the flutter versin 3.3.2 ?

Comment: I am using Flutter version 3.0.0.

Comment: For some reason, using the version `flutter_riverpod: ^1.0.0-dev.10` works but when I declare a global provider variable like `final helloWorldProvider = Provider((_) => 'Hello world');`. There is no recognition of the Provider class even after importing riverpod

Comment: @Samuel, did my edited answer help you?